# JQuery slideToggle function with separate close button

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide

I am having a bit of trouble getting the script to work. I dont know where i am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated please. Its learning in progress.

I have a toggle set up on my page that works fine, except that when the content div opens, i have a close button inside the open div that when clicked needs to close the content div. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".chairmanContent").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".chairmanReadmore").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next(".chairmanContent").slideToggle(500);
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".chairmanContent").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".chairmanClose").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next(".chairmanContent").slideUp(500);
  });
});
</script>
```

I am not sure if using slideUp is the correct way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so instead of `.next()` use `.closest()`:

change this:

```
jQuery(this).next(".chairmanContent").slideUp(500);
```

to this:

```
jQuery(this).closest(".chairmanContent").slideUp(500);
//-----------^-----^---------use closest here.
```

---

What seems to me is that your close button `"chairmanClose"` is inside this div `"chairmanContent"` so in this case you have to traverse up to your div with `.closest()`.

---

You can simplify your code this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".chairmanContent").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  $(".chairmanReadmore").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".chairmanContent").slideToggle(500);
  });

  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  $(".chairmanClose").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".chairmanContent").slideUp(500);
  });
});
</script>
```

You don't need two `jQuery(document).ready();` functions instead of it you can do it in a single doc ready method and you can use your `$` sign as an alias for jQuery the way i suggested.

Comment: This one worked perfectly ! thank you. Does this mean that when you want to reverse the action in a script we use .closest ? Sorry if my question seems a bit literal.

Comment: see if you are outmost of an elem and you want to get a grand child of that elem like `ul li ul` you can use `.find()` if you want to target the second `ul` in the `li` same way if you have done some event in the child or grand child elem then you have to traverse up to the elem you want to target with `.closest()`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation @Jai .. appreciate it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand completely, I write example code for you and dont have to use slideUp()

check it please : http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/m9RE4/

```
    $(".toggleSlide").click(function(){
        $(".content").slideToggle();
    });

    $(".closeContent").click(function(){
        $(".content").slideToggle();
    });
```